# Dual boot Windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04 problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8, windows-10

I had a dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

Last month I decided to uninstall and reinstall ubuntu due to some reasons. I deleted the disk ubuntu partition entirely and I also deleted grub. But somehow when I restarted my computer I was still seeing the grub console. To get out of that I had to type in exit three times to boot into Windows. I followed a guide and tried installing Ubuntu using Unetbootin but I couldn't. On top of that now I couldn't even boot into Windows. Instead, I got an error which said I corrupted the hard drive. Then I installed Windows 8(with a cd) on my machine to access Windows 10. So now I have Windows 8 and Windows 10 on my machine. During boot, I get the windows bootloader screen with 3 options --> Windows 10, Windows 8, Unetbootin.

Now I want too install Ubuntu 18.04 the right way and **uninstall Windows 8** from my pc but keep Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18 in dual-boot. Please help me. I am a complete newbie to Ubuntu and Linux.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you have some data to save do it.
- You have already deleted Ubuntu partition and you don't want Windows either, so no problem.
- Download Ubuntu ISO (and see other options) from [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
- Make a bootable USB [(see here)](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) or DVD [(see Here)](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#0).
- Boot from USB or DVD by selecting the option by pressing F8 or F12. For other kind of computers [see here.](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=58779#here)
- When asked choose 'Something else'.
- When asked choose the partition to install. So on..
- when completed reboot.
- Open gparted and delete Windows 8/10 partitions.
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Done.

Comment: I forgot to mention-- I want to keep Windows 10 in dual boot with Ubuntu 18. Edited that in now.

Comment: Delete only Windows 8 partition. Don't delete Windows 10 partition.